# $C_{0}(\mathbb{R})$ is not Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

The space $C_{0}(\mathbb{R})$ of all complex valued continuous function that vanish outside some finite interval is not an Hilbert space under the inner product

$$(f,g)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\overline{g(x)}\, dx$$

I tried to find out functions such that they violate parallelogram identity, but can't find out. Need help.

Comment: Let $f_n(x)  = e^{-|x|} \min(1,\max(0,n-|x|))$. Each $f_n$ is in $C_0$ but the limit $(x) = e^{-|x|}$ is not. (And $f_n \to f$ with the above metric.)

Comment: Note that your space is usually called $C_{c}(\Bbb R)$ or even $C_{00}(\Bbb R)$, $C_0(\Bbb R)$ in contrast usually is used to denote the set of continuous functions "vanishing at infinity" (that is those $f$ for which $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} f(x)=0$).

Answer (score 11):

And you won't find them, since $(\cdot,\cdot)$ *is* an inner product. The problem lies elsewhere: your space is not a complete metric space.